# C# how to wait for a proxy ping?

Tags: c#, proxy, wait, ping

I'm trying to ping a proxy, and time how long the response takes to get the ping before proceeding with my code, however my stopwatch is far too fast. Where am I going wrong here?

```
    private async void idunno()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();


        var x = await CanPing2();
        Console.WriteLine("is proxy alvie: " + x);
        stopWatch.Stop();

        int ts = stopWatch.Elapsed.Milliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + ts);



        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + ts2);
    }
    public async Task<bool> CanPing2()
    {

        string ip = "170.130.59.107";
        Console.WriteLine(ip);
        Ping ping = new Ping();

        try
        {
            PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, 6000);
            if (reply == null) return false;
            Console.WriteLine("cp2 is alive: " + IPStatus.Success);
            return (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
        }
        catch (PingException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("cp2: ex: " + IPStatus.Success);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What times are you getting right now and what are you expecting?

Comment: I get 2-600ms, I'm expecting 6000ish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `TimeSpan.Milliseconds` is actually the number of milliseconds since the last fully elapsed second, NOT the total number of elapsed milliseconds. i.e. If something runs for 1500 milliseconds, then the `Milliseconds` property will return 500, NOT 1500. You need to use `stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds` instead, which incidentally is a `double`, not an `int`.